# Outlook Add-in Notification Message or Flag Request

Tags: javascript, api, outlook, outlook-web-addins

I am trying to add a Flag/information message on an email item using Outlook Add-in javascript api. Is this possible? I am trying to achieve something similar to this one. Any assistance will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: I have noticed this link from Microsoft, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/apis It may be useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

From an Outlook addin, you can add a notification message via NotificationMessages API https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.notificationmessages?view=outlook-js-preview#addAsync_key__JSONmessage__options__callback_

Comment: Thank you. I managed to get it working on the email on my mailbox. However, when I am composing the email, I tried to add the notification as well on the email and I can see it showing on the Compose Message window. However, the email sent no longer has the notification I added.

Is this an expected behaviour, how can I add a notification on the email being composed and let it persist after sending it. Thank you.

Comment: Currently the feature to persist notifications through send, you requested, is not a part of the product. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our Tech Community Page. Please submit your request there and choose the appropriate label(s). Feature requests on Tech Community are considered, when we go through our planning process.

Github Label: “Type: product feature request”
https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions

Comment: @Margie the notification is preserved on the item in the Sent Items folder. However, the recipient won't receive the notification because it is not a transmittable property.